# White label a UWP Application

Tags: uwp, white-labelling

I am about to start development on an UWP Application. One of the last minute requirements was to be able to support white-labeling the application for our partners. Does anyone have any experience doing this using the Universal Windows Platform .
Question I have related to this:
1)Different approach by which the resources(colors/Themes) could be customized easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Different approach by which the resources(colors/Themes) could be customized easily.

You could try to localize strings in your UI and app package for different partners without changing any functions. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest). In the document, it mentions that you could store strings in a resources file. Then you could refer to the string using x:Uid directive for the target control. You will only need to change the source strings in the resource file depends on your requirements and you could let your app show different UI.

**Update**

For image resources, you could also use the localization.

Let's use Image control as an example. You could define a string called `firstImage.Source` and its value is `Assets/test.png` in the Resource file. Then in the xaml, the Image control uses x:Uid directive to refer to the control. This is the same as a TextBlock. If you want to change to another topic, what you need to do is just replace the old image with a new image in the Assets folder.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion.
Similarly is there any way to customize the image resources also

Comment: @sridhar patro, I've updated my reply, Please check that.